# How does the Temple Institute choose among disagreeing interpretations on Temple construction?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, machlokes, bigdei-kehunah

I was looking over R. Aryeh Kaplan's Chumash and I think he lists ... six different possible layouts of which tribe's name went on which stone in the breastplate (choshen).

Similarly -- is the *mor* in the incense an herb called myrrh in English, or is it an animal product? Different commentaries have different approaches.

So what does the Temple Institute (Machon HaMikdash) do when they plan on re-creating garments? What's their overall process of deciding like whom to pasken?

(I guess a broader question would be -- when Mashiach comes, will we be told from on high how to do it, or will the rabbis of the time just have to make their own judgment call?)

Comment: Why should it be different than any other case of psak?

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan Ha'asid brings a few opinions, but will say what he thinks

Comment: I’m voting to close because you can just ask them. Shoot them an email and you can share their response.

Comment: Are you only looking for an answer that specifically addresses the Temple Institute’s policy? Or would an answer that discusses the general issue of deciding between the multiple opinions be acceptable?

Comment: The third and fourth paragraphs [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19697&st=&pgnum=145) raise this issue with regard to different opinions about the Urim V'tumim.

Comment: @LN6595 How is this question not about Judaism just because you can ask them?

Answer (score 1):

The [Temple Institue](http://www.templeinstitute.org/choshen-mishpat-gallery.htm) has apparently chosen one of the opinions for the Choshen Mishpat. The web site statement does not say who determined this particular psak.
However, the [research page](https://www.templeinstitute.org/about.htm#research) states that this was examined by a team of experts in halacha as well as gemologists.

> The stones of the breastplate - recently created - were investigated
>   with the help of professional gemologists, geologists and other
>   experts. The wide range of material necessitated the examination of
>   over 30 differing viewpoints for establishing the criteria for
>   identifying the stones.

The story of the [Avtinas family](https://www.templeinstitute.org/incense.htm) implies that the method of making the incense is still not known.

Comment: Interesting! They're addressing "how to translate *bareket*" ... for that you can consult archeologists and gemologists... another question is slightly more basic -- what is the order for the names of the tribes? That's one that really goes just to the rabbis.

Comment: @Shalom According to the research page they have consulted s number of rabbis to decide that and did come up with a psak. See the link I show for the Choshen Mishpat